# need specific filtered output

Tags: powershell

I try this command

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" |
  Select macaddress | Select -Last 1
```

and I want to get rid off the formatting table where says macaddress.

How do I do that? I want only the macaddress and not the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) selects the properties of objects (among other things). The result remains a list of objects, though (the tabular output displays the properties of the objects). If you want just the value of a particular property, you need to expand it:

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" |
  Select -Expand macaddress | Select -Last 1
```

**Edit:** As @FrodeF mentioned in the comments, you can also merge the 2 `Select-Object` statements into one:

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" |
  Select -Expand macaddress -Last 1
```

Note, however, that in this case the `-Last 1` applies to the input of that `Select-Object`, not the selected property. This works for MAC addresses, because each network adapter can have only one, but it may not produce the desired result in other scenarios. Example:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
>> ? { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } |
>> select -Expand IPAddress -Last 1
>>
192.168.56.99
fe80::21ba:e68c:ebd0:1046
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
>> ? { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } |
>> select -Expand IPAddress | select -Last 1
>>
fe80::21ba:e68c:ebd0:1046
```

Here the `IPAddress` property has 2 values (IPv4 address and IPv6 address). So, in the first case `select -Expand IPAddress -Last 1` selects the last adapter configuration object, then expands the IP address list. In the second case `select -Expand IPAddress | select -Last 1` expands the IP address lists of all adapters, then selects the last item of the resulting list.

Comment: You should also combine the two `Select-Object`-calls to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty MacAddress -Last 1`

Comment: Guys you are big helpers. I have done whole process to achieve what you provide me in on line. Sorry but I am newbie. The command get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | Select -Expand macaddress -Last 1 does what I want. I do want now to pass this macaddress to html string : curl --data "identifier={\"type\":\"mac\", \"value\":\"00:00:00:00\"}&timestamp=1457821788&payload={\"message\":\"payload message\"}" 192.168.10.12:29017/event-logger/kk/ ...I need to fill out the mac in here. Any help would be appreciated. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Stratos Please do not move the target. If you have a new question (or a followup question): post it as a new question.